# Запретить повторное выполнение программы Python (pyinstaller -> exe) в Windows

Tags: python, windows

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли каким-нибудь образом реализовать запрет на повторный запуск уже запущенной программы Python, упакованной при помощи Pyinstaller? Нашел реализацию с использованием файла и реализацию с использованием сокета, но, возможно, есть более элегантный способ сделать это в Windows. Спасибо

Comment: Не элегантный, но примитивный способ: изменить заголовок исполняемого консольного окна. А при запуске Python проверять, есть ли в системе окно с таким заголовком. Если уже есть окно - выходим.